# How to jQuery autocomplete with JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For below JSON

```
{
  "partnerNameListBeanStruts2Map": [
    {
      "firstName": "sachin",
      "partnerId": 123
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Ankit",
      "partnerId": 234
    }
  ]
}
```

What code should I wright to done jQuery autocompleter.

Here is my code.

Here I want autocomplete element's value is like sachin OR ankit and id is like like 123 OR 234 is id of element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                        url : "list.action",
                        type : "POST",
                        data : {
                            term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(data) 
                        {
                        ****What should I write here to work my code?****
                        }
                });
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Sorry sir.Now I added .

Comment: @SachinDave Share a fiddle link with your html code + jason data

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), You should return your data with the `response` callback function.

> A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

```
$(function($) {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                        url : "list.action",
                        type : "POST",
                        data : {
                            term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(data) 
                        {
                            ***response (data) ;***
                        }
                });
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i want autocompleter value as bulwark1 and key as 1.What should i do ?

Comment: An autocomplete object has two property, one is `label`, the other is `value`.  Could you be more specific what is your `autocomplete element's value ` and `id of element` mean.

Comment: {
  "partnerNameListBeanStruts2Map": [
    {
      "firstName": "sachin",
      "partnerId": 123
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Ankit",
      "partnerId": 234
    }
  ]
}

Comment: First step, you should modify your object format to correspond jquery UI's requirement. Try : `[{label : "sachin", value : 123},{label : "Ankit",value:234}]`  and you will see new result. And I still can't understand whether this is what you expected.